# ¿Como puedo eliminar una colección completa de Firestore desde mi pagina Web?

Tags: javascript, html5, firebase, firestore

estoy programando una pagina donde puedo recibir los pedidos de mi negocio, pero tengo miedo de que la memoria de firebase se llene con tantos pedidos, quería agregar una opción de limpiar la colección para ocupar mucho espacio. Estuve leyendo la documentacion de Firebase pero no me da la funcion que necesito para hacerlo. ¿Como lo puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desde la [documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#collections) detalla lo siguiente

> Para borrar por completo una colección o subcolección en Cloud
> Firestore, recupera todos los documentos de la colección o
> subcolección y bórralos. Si tienes colecciones más grandes, te
> recomendamos borrar los documentos en grupos pequeños para evitar
> errores de memoria insuficiente. Repite el proceso hasta que borres
> toda la colección o subcolección.
>
> Para borrar una colección, se debe coordinar una cantidad ilimitada de
> solicitudes de eliminación individuales. Si necesitas borrar
> colecciones completas, hazlo únicamente desde un entorno de servidor
> de confianza. Si bien es posible borrar una colección desde un cliente
> web o para dispositivos móviles, hacerlo tiene efectos negativos en el
> rendimiento y en la seguridad.

Si quisieras borrar una colección podrías intentar realizar lo que se especifica en esta [sección](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections#cloud_function)

Básicamente no podes borrar una colección completa por que no hay ninguna API de firebase que te lo permita, lo que si se puede hacer es iterar sobre la colección y en borrar todos los documentos uno por uno con una operacion por lotes, como no es atomico no te asegura que se cumpla para todos pero si puede servirte.

Te dejo un snipet de lo que podría llegar a ser el código

```
db.collection("tuColeccion")
  .get()
  .then(res => {
    res.forEach(element => {
      element.ref.delete();
    });
  });
```